# How to treat missing attribute values in the Information Gain Attribute Evaluation

Tags: java, weka, information-theory

I'm trying to evaluate a selection of attributes using the information gain library provided by weka, but it's not working if the attribute which decides how an instance is classified, does not always provide a value. It's hard to explain, so here is an example:

This is my relation. It consists of 3 numeric attributes and a class attribute. The classification is set to failing if the attribute 3 takes the value 5000.

```
@relation TEST

@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 numeric
@attribute attr3 numeric
@attribute class {failing,correct}

@data
8,  0.519674, 5000, failing
?,  6.78149,  ?,    correct
?,  7.384081, 5000, failing
21, ?,        ?,    correct
5,  1.016151, 5000, failing
```

After executing the Information Gain Attribute Evaluator, this is the output:

```
=== Attribute Selection on all input data ===

Search Method:
    Attribute ranking.

Attribute Evaluator (supervised, Class (nominal): 4 class):
    Information Gain Ranking Filter

Ranked attributes:
 0.249  1 attr1
 0      3 attr3
 0      2 attr2

Selected attributes: 1,3,2 : 3
```

Now, attribute 3 should be the highest ranking, as it's value decides whether the instance is classified as failing or as correct. But that's somehow not the case.

So, my question: **How do I tell WEKA to use missing values in the calculation of the information gain?**

One possibility would be to replace the missing value by a constant like this:

```
@relation TEST

@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 numeric
@attribute attr3 numeric
@attribute class {failing,correct}

37, 9.295889,  5000, failing
48, ?,         0,    correct
35, 14.722155, 5000, failing
?,  11.417347, 0,    correct
?,  4.539502,  5000, failing
```

Then the ranking works:

```
=== Attribute Selection on all input data ===

Search Method:
    Attribute ranking.

Attribute Evaluator (supervised, Class (nominal): 4 class):
    Information Gain Ranking Filter

Ranked attributes:
 0.971  3 attr3
 0.249  1 attr1
 0      2 attr2

Selected attributes: 3,1,2 : 3
```

But that's not really what I want, as I can't predict the values my attribute 3 will have.

Here's my code:

```
 public static void test() {
        FastVector attributes = new FastVector();
        Random rand = new Random();

        Attribute attr1 = new Attribute("attr1");
        Attribute attr2 = new Attribute("attr2");
        Attribute attr3 = new Attribute("attr3");

        attributes.addElement(attr1);
        attributes.addElement(attr2);
        attributes.addElement(attr3);

        FastVector classValues = new FastVector(2);
        classValues.addElement("failing");
        classValues.addElement("correct");
        Attribute classAttribute = new Attribute("class", classValues);
        attributes.addElement(classAttribute);

        Instances instances = new Instances("TEST", attributes, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Instance instance = new Instance(4);
            instance.setDataset(instances);

            if (i % (rand.nextInt(4) + 1) == 0)
                instance.setValue(attr1, rand.nextInt(50));

            if (i % (rand.nextInt(4) + 1) == 0)
                instance.setValue(attr2, rand.nextFloat() * 15);

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                instance.setValue(attr3, 5000);
                instance.setValue(classAttribute, "failing");
            } else {
                //instance.setValue(attr3, 0);
                instance.setValue(classAttribute, "correct");
            }

            instances.add(instance);
        }

        instances.setClass(classAttribute);
        instances.compactify();
        System.out.println(instances);

        try {
            System.out.println(AttributeSelection.SelectAttributes(new InfoGainAttributeEval(), new String[]{"-s", "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker"}, instances));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!